# Invalid use of incomplete type class error when inheriting from class defined externally

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following folder structure:

```
src/
├── drivers
│   ├── drv_rs485_bus.h
│   └── rs485_bus
│       ├── rs485_device.cpp
│       └── rs485_device.h
└── modules
    └── dx_servos
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── dx_servo.cpp
        └── dx_servo.h
```

In `rs485_device.h` is a class:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include "rs485_bus.h"

namespace rs485 {

class Rs485Device {
   public:
    explicit Rs485Device(std::shared_ptr<rs485::Rs485Bus> bus, uint8_t address);
    ~Rs485Device();

   private:
    std::shared_ptr<rs485::Rs485Bus> _bus;
    uint8_t _address;
};

}  // ns: rs485
```

`drv_rs485_bus.h` exposes the class `Rs485Device`, and is supposed to be included by anything that should use the class. It has the following content:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

namespace rs485 {

class Rs485Bus;
class Rs485Device;

extern std::shared_ptr<Rs485Bus>
get_bus();
extern bool
get_open();
}
```

Now, I want to make a class, `DxServo`, which inhertis `Rs485Device`. I include `drv_rs485_bus.h`, and declare `DxServo` like this:

```
#pragma once

#include <drivers/drv_rs485_bus.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

namespace dx_servo {

class DxServo : public rs485::Rs485Device {
   public:
    explicit DxServo(const std::string name, uint16_t address,
                     std::shared_ptr<rs485::Rs485Bus> bus);
    ~DxServo();

   private:
    uint16_t _address;
    std::shared_ptr<rs485::Rs485Bus> _bus;
};

}  // ns: dx_servo
```

Now, when compiling, I get the following error:

```
../src/modules/dx_servos/dx_servo.h:12:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class rs485::Rs485Device’
 class DxServo : public rs485::Rs485Device {
                               ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

What may be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to inherit from a class you need the full definition, not only a forward declaration. You need to include the `rs485_device.h` header file.